# Parse classes add relation

Tags: parse-server

How do I relate to classes in my Parse server.

For example, I have these two classes.

a. Product
b. Category

I want to relate the two classes in order for there data to be related also. where product's data are connected to category's. So to return the each value submitted. there's a relation of classes needed.

I tried relating each of its objectId's but its not very efficient because there's a lot data inside each classes. so I want to relate the classes itself. but how?

Answer (score 0):

Not possible.  You can only relate class objects to other class objects, using a pointer or relation.